# How to add content to user profile page in Drupal 7?

Tags: drupal, rendering, user-accounts

I'm trying to add a couple of sections onto the user profile in Drupal 7 under:

`<div class="profile" typeof="sioc:UserAccount" about="/drupal/user/1">`

I'm adding three new sections, but the problem is that, although I am using the same way to add the three sections, only one of them is rendered as a child of the div above, while the other two are rendered as siblings. What am I doing wrong?

This is how I'm creating the content:

```
function plan_user_user_view($account) {    
//Create the markup for the events region
$account->content['events'] = array(
  '#type' => 'user_profile_item',
  '#theme' => 'events',
  '#events' => $events);

 //Create the region for the venues
  $account->content['venues'] = array(
   '#type' => 'user_profile_item',
   '#theme' =>'venues',
   '#userid' => $user->uid,
   '#venues' => $venues);

  //Create the region for creating an event
  $account->content['creator'] = array(
    '#prefix' => '<div class="user-event-item" id="quick-event-creator">',
    '#suffix' => '</div>',
    '#type' => 'user_profile_item',
    '#title' => t('QUICK EVENT CREATOR'),
    '#markup' => drupal_render(drupal_get_form('event_creation')));
 }
```

Also, is there a better way to create that last piece of content there? The other two seem fine in a template file but the last one since it's a form I was wondering if there are better ways of doing that.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should have a look on this project [profil2](http://drupal.org/project/profile2) which is the successor of content_profil for Drupal 6. With it you will be able to add informations onto users profils and if you want to code your custom fields by yourself it should be a good starting point to read.

Best.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
// Create the category.
$account->content['mymodule'] = array(
    '#type' => 'user_profile_category',
    '#title' => t('My module content'),
);

// Create first item (child).
$account->content['mymodule']['events'] = array(
    '#type' => 'user_profile_item',
    '#title' => t('Events'),
    '#markup' => t('Whatever'),
);

// Create second item (child).
$account->content['mymodule']['venues'] = array(
    '#type' => 'user_profile_item',
    '#title' => t('Venues'),
    '#markup' => t('Whatever'),
);
```

and so on. The bottom line is that `user_profile_item` items should be children of a `user_profile_category` item.